# Decoding string in python3

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, decode, encode

How can I convert

```
str1 = 'Sabrau00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'
```

to

```
final_str = 'Sabra® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17oz'` in python3.
```

I have tried:

1. `str1.encode('utf-8') html.unescape`
2. `str1.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')`
3. `str1.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')`

But no luck.

Output of `isinstance(str1,str)` is `True`
Output of `str1.encode('utf=8')` is bytes string `b'Sabrau00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'`

I also imported charade, but I got errors in the encoding and decode function.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'  
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Mark Tolonen for help on the regex. In your output, I was getting 'u' also in the name along with the decoded symbol. So, I fixed the edge cases using the below code by

1. Finding the substring with 'u' and 4 digit/characters next to it.
2. converting this substring to Unicode string using replace function
3. decoding using Unicode-escape

Below code works:

```
def convert(s):
    # return re.sub(r'[0-9A-F]{4}',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(),16)), s)
    return str.encode(re.sub(r'u[0-9A-F]{4}',lambda m:(m.group().replace('u','\\u')),s),'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Input:

```
 str1 = 'Sabrau00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'
```

Code:

```
str2=convert(str1)
print (str2)
print(type(str2))
```

Output:

```
Sabra® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `\u`; use this to precede the codepoint and it will render the correct unicode character.

```
>>> str1 = 'Sabrau\u00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'
>>> str1
'Sabrau® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'
```

Comment: This works when we have \u in the string. But the string we are getting is without \u. str1 = 'Sabrau00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz' 
 How to convert it to 'Sabrau\u00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz' so that final operation can be applied.

Comment: OP already has a string without a \u escape code.  \u escapes only work when creating string literals in source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your string doesn't have a standard encoding and could be ambiguous.  Assuming that any time "four hexadecimal digits in a row" means "insert Unicode code point", then below works, but note *any* `u` with 4-digits will convert to a Unicode character, such as "Plateau1000 Protein Powder" would become "Plateaက Protein Powder":

```py
import re

# 1. locate u followed by 4 hexdigits
# 2. capture digits and convert to an integer using base 16
# 3. convert integer to a Unicode char
# 4. use character as the substitution for the digits
def convert(s):
    return re.sub(r'u([0-9A-F]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)), s)

str1 = 'Sabrau00AE Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz'
str2 = convert(str1)
print(str2)
```

Output:

```
Sabra® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz
```

Comment: This works, but getting u along with symbol. i.e. Your output: Sabrau® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz Desired output : Sabra® Family Size Roasted Pine Nut Hummus - 17 oz. I have fixed that in my answer below. Thanks.

Comment: @Shivangi._k Ah, didn't spot the `u` was part of the escape code, hence my comment that it was ambiguous.  Edited answer.